# Populate dropdown list based on a Radio button selection in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a dropdown options based on a radio button selection.

Here is my code below

**HTML**

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="cat_type">

<md-radio-button  ng-repeat="category in  categories" value="{{ category }}" class="md-primary">
{{ category.name }}</md-radio-button>

</md-radio-group>

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="cat_list" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in cat_type.types"></select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.categories= [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Allowance",
        "types": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "category_id": 1,
                "name": "Overtime"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "category_id": 1,
                "name": "Bonuses"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Deduction",
        "types": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "category_id": 2,
                "name": "Loan"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "category_id": 2,
                "name": "surcharges"
            }
        ]
    }
     ]
```

It lists the radio buttons, but on click of any radio item, nothing happens to the  options

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a model for radio button and then use category.types in ng-options

Comment: That is exactly what I did.